# How should PHP command-line scripts be structured?

Tags: php, coding-style, command-line-interface

This is a PHP coding style question.

I create a lot of PHP command-line scripts, but I'm never sure exactly how they should be structured. I don't feel comfortable having all of my code be global, so I've been wrapping my entire app in a class:

```
<?php

class MyApp {

    public function parseCommandLine() {
        /* Parsing takes place here. */
    }

    public function doWork() {
        echo "This is all this app does.\n";
    }

    public function run() {
        $this->parseCommandLine();
        $this->doWork();
    } 
}

$app = new MyApp();
$app->run();
```

My question is: **Is this the best way to structure a modern, CLI-based PHP app?**

There are a ton of great guides that cover PHP best practices (my personal favorite is [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/)), but almost none of them cover how command-line apps should be structured.

Comment: Are you making interactive CLI utilities? If you are then the difference is mostly in the interface (how in- and output is handled). If not then it is almost exactly the same as making a website (you just have a request and a response; input and output). Also, why use PHP? It is possible to use PHP, of course, but that is not really what it was made for. It also has the downside that you need PHP installed, in order to be able to use it. I have found that Go is an easy language to learn, and it is easy to write CLI utilities with it. Just a suggestion.

Comment: The CLI utilities are not really interactive. They do take command-line flags, but that's where the interaction ends. I do like Go quite a bit. The main reason I'm using PHP is because all of the other code for my company is in PHP, and I'm leveraging a lot of those classes.

Comment: @DavidH You can ask for user input, which is everything you need to make interactive CLI apps.

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly opinion based but why reinvent the wheel? You're probably best served using a well designed third party php library developed for your use cases.

To create PHP cli based application, my personal favorite is [**symfony console**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html).

To run third party system commands and binaries, you can have a [**look at this library**](https://github.com/tivie/command) that let's you execute external commands in a safer way and harmonizes OS differences.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about symfony's console component. It looks really nice.